# How to find where process is blocked using postsharp

Tags: c#, winforms, postsharp

I have a winforms application that randomly gets frozen and I want to try to find out where, using postsharp.  I managed to create logs of every entry and exit. but is there a way to find out what method was entered and not exited?

Comment: Can you tell more Details of your application? Have you got timers or synclocks?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use PostSharp [Deadlock Detection](http://doc.postsharp.net/deadlock-detection) feature, which has been designed precisely for this purpose.